# What is the best way to create smaller size layout for an activity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a requirement that when user clicks on "View Card" button, open a smaller size activity that is not covering the complete screen.

I did and some R&D and find out multiple options for achieving this.

1- Create a layout file, and create a custom Dialog in your activity like following.

```
    //OnClickListener 

         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
   //this can have buttons and other stuff
```

2- Create a `Dialog Fragment`

3- Create a new activity, and add following line in the Manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

I am unable to understand which one is better approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **custom** **theme** for you activity in styles, with a custom navigation icon for example:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp</item>
</style>
```

Then, you can add this theme to your activity, in **Manifest**:

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
```

In this moment, you have a activity with a custom theme based in Dialog. If you want to put **width** and **height** custom **values** to your root layout, you can do it:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"/>

 <!-- Your activity content... -->

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's depend on you whether use activity,dialog.
for eg :
If data is short and just need to show/write some small info then use dialog.
Even you could try hidden (view/layout) and on click show that hidden (view/layout) with some animation ,after work hide.
even you can use now bottomsheet too :)